# What does $\limsup_{r \to 0} r^{-p}⨍_{B(x_0,r)} f^{q}(x) dx < \infty $ imply on the behavior of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}_+$. What does the following condition imply on the behavior of $f$?

> $$\limsup_{r \to 0} r^{-p}⨍_{B(x_0,r)} f^{q}(x) \ \mathrm{d}x < \infty,$$
>   $$p,q\ge 1, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N.$$

I thought we could use Lebesgue's differentiation lemma in some way, but I'm not clear how.

Comment: For locally bounded functions this looks like a local Hölder condition (with exponent $p$). So $p$ being greater than $1$ will imply that your function is constant (and equal to $0$).

Comment: Is your condition for every $x_0$ or for some $x_0$?

Answer (score 0):

To make sense of the statement assume that $f$ is locally in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so $f^q$ is locally in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. By Lebesgue Differentiation theorem we have that, a.e.
$$
 f(x)^q = \lim_{r \to 0^+} ⨍_{B(x,r)} f(y)^q \,d\,y = \limsup_{r \to 0^+} ⨍_{B(x,r)} f(y)^q \,d\,y
$$
But, by hypothesis, you have that
$$
  ⨍_{B(x,r)} f(y)^q \,d\,y \leq C \, r^p
$$
for $r$ small enough and $C$ large. Thus, $\, f(x)^q = 0$ almost everywhere.

**Remark**: The Hölder condition I was referring to appears when you substract the original function. I.e. the following condition is equivalent to be Hölder of exponent $0 < \alpha < 1$
$$
 \Big| \, f(x) - ⨍_{B(x,r)} f(y) \, d \, y \,  \Big| \leq C r^\alpha.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few additional questions about it though: **1.** Why do you conclude that $f(x)^q = 0$ a.e.? **2.** Can we say anything about the derivatives of $f$? **3.** How do you prove the result in your remark?

Comment: For **1**: As $r \to 0^+$, so does $r^q$, and so the averages go to $0$ and so it is $0$ almost everywhere. **2** Of course if it is $0$, it is derivable. For **3** If you change the average over $B(x,r)$ by the Poisson semigroup $P_r$, the case is well covered in Stein's "Singular integrals and differentiability of integrals". I do not recall a concrete reference for the fact above as I have state it

Comment: For your third question you can look at Theorem 2.3 (III) with $p= \infty$ of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212289.pdf. Although, probably there are more elementary references with the fact.